# Error updating SoftLayer tags

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to add **tags** to my SoftLayer machine using the program below:

```
hardware_service = SoftLayer::Service.new("SoftLayer_Hardware", :username => "abc", :api_key => "123", :timeout => 999)

machine =  hardware_service.object_with_id(123456).getObject
pp machine.addTags("test")
```

This program fails with the error that Function (`"addTags"`) is not a valid method for this service. Any help to fix this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following Ruby script using SoftLayer_Hardware::setTags. Apparently “addTags” is not working as expected.

Example:

```
# Set tags for a Bar metal
#
# The script sets the tags for a Bar metal,
# it makes a single call to the SoftLayer_Hardware::setTags method
# For more information please see below.
#
# Important manual pages:
# http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware/setTags
#
# License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
# Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
require 'softlayer_api'
require 'pp'

# Your SoftLayer username and API key.
USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

# The Hardware Id you wish to set the tags
hardware_id = 122145
# The tags you wish to set in the server
tags = 'mytag1, mytag2'

client = SoftLayer::Client.new(username: USERNAME, api_key: API_KEY)
virtual_guest_service = client['SoftLayer_Hardware']

begin
  # Sending the request to get the tags
  result = virtual_guest_service.object_with_id(hardware_id).setTags(tags)
  pp result
rescue StandardError => exception
  pp "Unable to set the tags. : #{exception}"
end
```

**References:**

> http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware/setTags

**Note:**
If your server has a previous tag, it has to be included in the set of tags when executing the script. Otherwise it will be overwriten.